# Placement of turtle drawn letters in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm new to this but wanted to try Python with turtle. But I have a problem with my code when I tell the cursor to move to underneath the letter H.  It just throws cursor at the start where the H is.  I wanna write:

```
HAPPY
BDAY
```

in that order.  Here is the code i have so far.

```
import turtle
frame = turtle.Screen().bgcolor("Red")
hi = turtle.Turtle()

hi.color("Black")
hi.width (3)
hi.speed (3)

# H
hi.left(90)
hi.forward(70)
hi.penup()
hi.goto(0, 35)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(90)
hi.forward(30)
hi.penup()
hi.goto(30, 70)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(90)
hi.forward(70)

# A
hi.penup()
hi.goto(40, 0)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(200)
hi.forward(75)
hi.right(140)
hi.forward(75)
hi.penup()
hi.goto(50, 35)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(-70)
hi.forward(31)

# P
hi.penup()
hi.goto(105, 70)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(90)
hi.forward(70)
hi.penup()
hi.goto(105,35)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(275)
hi.circle(18, 200)

# PP
hi.penup()
hi.goto(140, 70)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(285)
hi.forward(70)
hi.penup()
hi.goto(140,35)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(275)
hi.circle(18, 200)

# Y
hi.penup()
hi.goto(170, 70)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(255)
hi.forward(40)
hi.right(30)
hi.forward(35)
hi.penup()
hi.goto(190, 35)
hi.pendown()
hi.right(215)
hi.forward(40)

#B
hi.penup()
hi.goto(200, 70)
hi.pendown()
hi.forward(70)

turtle.mainloop()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2f4C.jpg the white dots are where I want the word Bday to start but the turtle is in the position where the arrow is.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to do that you can't? Be specific.

Comment: When u run the code i want it to draw letters Happy Bdayin all caps. But when i come to the letter B and start to code it the turtle dosent go to position i tell it too go so i cant code a letter B

Answer (score 1):

You can only eyeball and guess so far.  For text like this, it helps to have a fixed size box that each letter is going to fit into, and a constant location where the cursor is going to be in that box when letter drawing begins.  It also helps to use relative positioning, like `forward()` rather than absolute positioning like `goto()`, when trying to debug your letters:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('red')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.width(3)

# letters are in a box 30 wide by 70 tall with 10px between
# the pen starts at the lower left of each letter box

# H
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(70)
turtle.backward(35)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(30)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(35)
turtle.backward(70)

turtle.penup()
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(10)
turtle.pendown()

# A
turtle.left(78)  # 77.9 degrees is rise 70 over run 15
turtle.forward(74)
turtle.right(156)
turtle.forward(37)
turtle.right(102)
turtle.forward(16)
turtle.backward(16)
turtle.left(102)
turtle.forward(37)

turtle.penup()
turtle.left(78)
turtle.forward(10)
turtle.pendown()

# P
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(70)
turtle.backward(35)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(17.5)
turtle.circle(17.5, 180)
turtle.forward(17.5)

turtle.penup()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(70)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(40)
turtle.pendown()

# PP
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(70)
turtle.backward(35)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(17.5)
turtle.circle(17.5, 180)
turtle.forward(17.5)

turtle.penup()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(70)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(40)
turtle.pendown()

# Y
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(15)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(35)
turtle.left(23)  # 90 - 67 as 66.8 degrees is rise 35 over run 15
turtle.forward(38)
turtle.backward(38)
turtle.right(46)
turtle.forward(38)
turtle.backward(38)
turtle.left(23)
turtle.backward(35)

turtle.penup()
turtle.right(90)
turtle.goto(0, -75)  # 5px between lines of text
turtle.pendown()

# B
turtle.forward(17.5)
turtle.circle(17.5, 180)
turtle.forward(17.5)
turtle.right(180)
turtle.forward(17.5)
turtle.circle(17.5, 180)
turtle.forward(17.5)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(70)

turtle.penup()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(40)
turtle.pendown()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Now you're in position to draw "D" in a 70x30 box with the cursor in the lower left corner pointing right.